# Can't find a way to fix Unity!

Tags: unity, window-manager

I did everything I could do that was listed on [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears), but even with unity, nothing is happening! All I can see is my desktop and my desktop Icons! I can open programs that are on my desktop fine, but I can't close or move or minimize them! I can minimize and close Google Chrome, however. Any help on what to do? Rough and Improvised picture can be shown. I am currently using my functional guest account.

Comment: Can you tell us specifically which steps you followed on the linked article?

Comment: All of the listed answers posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to:

**Restore default settings**

Execute the following commands in terminal, one at time.

```
gconftool --shutdown
sudo killall -r -I gconf
sudo killall -r -I dconf
rm -rf .compiz* .gconf* .config/dconf/ .config/compiz*
```

**Be aware** that above commands will remove any settings or configuration you've done already. Keyboard layouts (if any) will also be removed. Although above commands will not delete any files, they will restore Unity settings as were, when you installed Ubuntu for the first time.

Reboot your system for changes to take effect.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I'm kinda sad that almost everything is gone, but it worked. Thanks!!!